# how to interpret the p-values on models with significant interaction terms on glmer?

Tags: interaction, mixed-models, p-value

I am testing differences on pollen deposition between two habitats (invaded and non-invaded) and three different stigma types (wet, dry and semidry). It is a community approach, with unbalanced number of samples and species per site, and non-normal distribution of data, which ended up having a nested random structure, fitted with gamma error distribution, to deal with pseudoreplication and non-independence.

To find out the best model, I used likelihood ratio test, that shows the model with interactions of the fixed effects would fit better:

```
 > m1b<-glmer(nb~habitat*stigmatype+(1|sitecode/stigmaspecies), family=Gamma(link=log))
 > m2b<-glmer(nb~habitat+stigmatype+(1|sitecode/stigmaspecies), family=Gamma(link=log))
 > anova(m1b,m2b)
Data: 
Models:
m2b: nb ~ habitat + stigmatype + (1 | sitecode/stigmaspecies)
m1b: nb ~ habitat * stigmatype + (1 | sitecode/stigmaspecies)
Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
m2b  7 3032.8 3061.3 -1509.4   3018.8                           
m1b  9 3030.1 3066.7 -1506.0   3012.1 6.6672      2    0.03566 *
```

From there, I am getting a bit confused on how to interpret the p-values of the fixed terms.
Looking at the output below, can i interpret the p-values of habitat and stigma type as independent results of the interaction term? 
Re-wording, can I say that the variable habitat has a significant influence per se, such that habitat non-invaded is different that habitat invaded (intercept)? And the same thinking to stigma type? 
Or since interaction is slightly significant, I cant interpret the fixed values independently anymore? And only a post-hoc test would tell where the differences in fact are?

```
m1b<-glmer(nb~habitat*stigmatype+(1|sitecode/stigmaspecies), family=Gamma(link=log))
summary(m1b)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
Family: Gamma ( log )
Formula: nb ~ habitat * stigmatype + (1 | sitecode/stigmaspecies) 

  AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
 3030.101  3066.737 -1506.050  3012.101 

 Random effects:
 Groups                 Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 stigmaspecies:sitecode (Intercept) 5.209e+00 2.2822436
 sitecode               (Intercept) 2.498e-07 0.0004998
 Residual                           2.070e+00 1.4388273
 Number of obs: 433, groups: stigmaspecies:sitecode, 109; sitecode, 20

 Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)                            2.3824     0.4080   5.839 5.26e-09 ***
 habitatnon-invaded                    -1.8270     0.6425  -2.843  0.00446 ** 
 stigmatypesemidry                     -1.7531     0.7573  -2.315  0.02061 *  
 stigmatypewet                         -1.7210     0.8944  -1.924  0.05434 .  
 habitatnon-invaded:stigmatypesemidry   2.0774     1.1440   1.816  0.06938 
 habitatnon-invaded:stigmatypewet       1.3120     1.4741   0.890  0.37346
```

> thank you very much for you thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Try graphing your data. Does it look like invaded sites are always higher/lower than un-invaded, or is there not a clear pattern?
If the picture is not very clear, I recommend post-hoc tests.
I've just done a similar post-hoc analysis using this code:

```
levels(data$habitat)
levels(data$stigmatype)#I believe 1 is the first value that is returned when you run levels(), 0 is the next, and -1 the last

testInteractions(m1b, custom=list(habitat='invaded', stigmatype=c(1,0,-1), adjustment="none"))
testInteractions(m1b, custom=list(habitat='non-invaded', stigmatype=c(1,0,-1), adjustment="none"))

testInteractions(m1b, custom=list(stigmatype='wet', habitat=c(1,-1), adjustment="none"))
testInteractions(m1b, custom=list(stigmatype='dry', habitat=c(1,-1), adjustment="none"))
testInteractions(m1b, custom=list(stigmatype='semidry', habitat=c(1,-1), adjustment="none"))
```